# Trying to do a scatterplot using seaborn but it throws some error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a scatterplot using seaborn but i'm getting a key-error.

```
import pandas as pd


census_data = pd.read_csv('census_data1.csv')
sns.scatterplot(x=census_data['capital_loss'], y=census_data['capital_gain'])
```

this is the screenshot of the error[image]

[image]

capital_loss is an integer field

[image]

but when I plot age vs age it gets plotted
[image]

unable to figure out why this is happening

Comment: The print of the dataframe columns gives the impression that all but a few of the column names start with a space. You could try renaming them. Or try `census_data[' capital_loss'`, although this might not work if the character only looks like a space and in reality is something else. Trying`x=census_data[11], y=census_data[10]` could shed some more light on what's really happening

Comment: ok, let me try this

Comment: so i figured out the answer, my actual csv file had a space character after every comma, that's why it was throwing the error. I removed all the spaces from my csv file and the code ran just fine